# getting mysql syntax error when trying to insert variable as table name and values

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, syntax, sql-insert

```
            if conn.is_connected():
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                sql = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `%s`(
                id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                rating VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
                reservation_rate VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
                )''' % day
                cursor.execute(sql)            


            x = 1
            for i in range(len(title_rank)):
                title = rank[0][i]
                rating = rank[1][i]
                reservation = rank[2][i]
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `%s`(id, title, rating, reservation_rate), (%d, %s, %s, %s))
                """%(day, x, title, rating, reservation))
                x += 1
                conn.commit()
```

while i was able to create table with no problem using above method, but for the second part of code i am getting syntax error and i do not know the reason. have tried to use format function but did not work.
this is the error i get:

1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', (1, 인비저블맨, rate: 6.7, 예매율25.2%))' at line 1

Comment: Why are you making tables per thing instead of using a relational table structure with one table and a column for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INSERT` form is:

```
INSERT INTO `%s`(id, title, rating, reservation_rate) VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s)
```

The `,` there is incorrect syntax.

You also need to be **absolutely sure** you're using `execute` with placeholder values:

```
 cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tablename (id, title, rating, reservation_rate), (%d, %s, %s, %s))
            """, (day, x, title, rating, reservation))
```

**NEVER** use string interpolation to do this with `%` instead. This opens you to [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: thank you for your help, but my question was if there anyways i can use the variable as the table name and insert variables as values too

Comment: Do everything you can do to avoid that, like not having a dynamic table name. If you must use a dynamic table name then compose that part of your query separately, like `("INSERT INTO %s (...)" % (day)) + " (%d, %...)", ( ...)`

Comment: In the vast majority of cases it's simply not worth having multiple tables like that broken out by day. It makes doing simple queries really infuriating. If you have so many records you need to split up the data somehow then you need table partitioning or horizontal sharding, not multiple tables with dynamic names.